# Can i stack both a lens and a (variable) ND filter on a phone camera?

Tags: lens, smartphone, cameraphones, nd-filter, mobile

I am o total noob so forgive the blunders.
I am interested in filming my travels with a Samsung S7 mobile phone, so the upper level of amateur is enough for me. So video, not photo.

What i want is to make use of phone camera lenses (telephoto, wide, macro) together with a variable ND filter.

My problems are:

1. Dont know if those combos are even possible. I see lense kits like this one (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neewer-Clip-Filter-iPhone-Android-Clear/dp/B07HQ6QYFC) that offer lenses and filters, but they describe each one individually, so i dont understand if i can mount the wide lens and put the ND filter on top, for instance.
2. Even if 1 is a possibility, i could not find a single kit that contains both a telephoto lens and an ND filter. Is there a limitation that prevents this particular combo?
3. Optionally, is there a way to stack a lens, an ND filter and a CPL filter all on top of each other?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: i would try duct tape XD and at this price it is worth a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to attach a filter to a lens, there needs to be some sort of attachment method.

In the kit you linked, the ND filter is a separate "clip-on" attachment to your phone. This means that it is not inherently designed to attach to a lens, but to your phone. Some rigging may be possible to get it to work, but it's not in the design.

Here's another [seller's lens option](https://www.shopmoment.com/shop/new-tele-lens). Notice in the product image how the lens appears to have threads. This is because this lens is designed to take a custom [Step-Up Ring](https://www.shopmoment.com/shop/filter-mount-62mm). This ring *also* has threads, allowing for the attachment of filters. The size of the ring at the attachment point for filters is 62mm - a standard size in the photo industry.

For example, [here's a store with 136 different options](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ci=114&fct=fct_circular-sizes_27%7C62mm&N=4026728350) for ND filters, all in the 62mm size.

[Same store, 70 different options for polarizing filters](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ci=115&fct=fct_circular-sizes_27%7C62mm&N=4026728357).

As you can see, in the world of photography, filters are pretty common place. What you need to add a filter to a phone camera lens is a lens manufacturer **that has designed their product to be used with the filters available** or who has **custom made the filters for their product**.

The manufacturer that you chose gives you the option of using the lens OR using the filter. Blame their product designer. If this is unsatisfactory to you, then shop around!

Answer (score 0):

Check out beastgrip...  it’s pretty awesome.  I have a BeastGrip Pro with the DOF adapter and a canon 50mm f/1.8.  I use normal filter kits on the 50mm lens. It’s not cheap, but it produces stellar results with my iPhone 7 Plus and Filmic Pro app for video or ProCamera app for photos.  I’ve used slide in type ND filter kits and screw on circular polarizing filters.  I paid about $300.00 US for the complete kit.